# list all folder name only in one line

Tags: linux

How list all folder name in the same line :
Because, I tried:

```
ls $workspace
```

I get

```
parm
shell
sql
```

But I want the final result look like :

```
parm shell sql
```

**NOTE**

I am writing this command in script window of the jenkins job.
And the command result should be saved in file named "folder1.txt"
So the original command is :

```
ls $WORKSPACE --ignore={"Jenkinsfile",".gitignore",".editorconfig","branches.txt","folders.txt"} > folder1.txt
```

I tried also :

```
ls -1 $WORKSPACE --ignore={"Jenkinsfile",".gitignore",".editorconfig","branches.txt","folders.txt"} > folder1.txt
```

But the command result given in folder1.txt, is

```
parm
shell
sql
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop `-1`:

```
$ ls $workspace --ignore={"Jenkinsfile",".gitignore",".editorconfig","branches.txt","folders.txt"}
parm  shell  sql
```

`-1` specifically makes ls `list one file per line`.

If you're redirecting `ls` output to a file use `-C` option:

```
ls -C  $workspace --ignore={"Jenkinsfile",".gitignore",".editorconfig","branches.txt","folders.txt"}  > list
```